# CSS: How to fit columns in rows

Tags: css

I have some count of DIVs and I need to display them in 2 equal columns. in case if one of the DIV bigger than 50% all DIVs should be displayed in 1 column
for example i have this - `jsfiddle.net/w2m0sjav/` and i should display it like - `jsfiddle.net/sxmp8bw0/`
if all DIVs are small than it should looks like - `jsfiddle.net/r4L0g5eb/`

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container .item {
    border-style: solid;
    min-width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very big answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D fixed. is it ok now and maybe you can help me ?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with flexbox....or any layout method. You're gonna need javascript,

Comment: @Paulie_D oh crap, I wanted to do this without JS ((

Answer (score 0):

Like some already mentioned in a comment, I don't think this is possible with CSS alone, however you can do it with a little bit of JS, snippet:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#container .item');

const containerHalfWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).width, 10) / 2;

items.forEach((item) => {
let itemWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(item).width, 10);
    if (itemWidth > containerHalfWidth) {
    // try commenting out this line below
    container.classList.add('one-column');
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container .item {
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* we want the cards to make 2 full columns inside container
     but also have 10px margins on either side of them */
  min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container.one-column .item {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very big answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
  <div class="item">small answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but this doesn't work (( 
https://www.screencast.com/t/FH8qwNSEV